# KeyError: 'user' when running Ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

**Edit**: Using python 3.6 made matters worse. Completely reinstalling python 2.7.15 did not solve it. The same error appears.

**Edit Again**: I created a new user, `test_user` and chown'd my ansible-web.txt file to that user (`sudo chown test_user:test_user ansible-web.txt`). I ran the playbook again and those errors did not show. So, it's something wrong in my local files. I just don't even know where to begin to look.

I am trying to figure out what is causing this error. It's repeated over and over when I try to run any of my Ansible playbooks, but the playbook still runs successfully. There are two errors. Here is the entire output of running the play for a single remote host:

```
< TASK [Gathering Facts] >
 ------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file transport.py, line 1819
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file transport.py, line 1819
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file sftp.py, line 158
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'user'
Logged from file sftp.py, line 158
ok: [192.168.80.50]
 ___________________________________
< TASK [test_ansible_facts : debug] >
 -----------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

skipping: [192.168.80.50]
 ___________________________________
< TASK [test_ansible_facts : debug] >
 -----------------------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

ok: [192.168.80.50] => {
    "msg": "OS version is 18.04"
}
 ____________
< PLAY RECAP >
 ------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||

192.168.80.50              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I don't really have a "what have you tried" response, because I haven't changed anything (except for basic software updates on my Ubuntu machine), and I don't know enough about Python to debug this. Searching for the specific error doesn't produce any results.

No matter which playbook I run, those errors show up. I'm using Ansible version 2.7.15 and Python 2.7.15.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: From the tracebacks and the fact that the playbook still executes successfully, the issue seems to stem from `logging`. Have you tried updating that package?

Comment: @JR. Forgive my confusion, but which package are you referring to? I have not updated any packages.

Comment: @JR. I ran `sudo pip install logging --upgrade`, but that did not change anything. Was that the package you were referring to?

Comment: I assumed it was a package, but it's a standard library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Disregard my original comment. Sorry I wasn't more helpful :-\

Comment: @JR. Updated my question with some new info.

Comment: The `chown` you did just raises more questions! Can you share the `ansible-playbook` command(s) you ran? Can you also share your `$PATH`?

Comment: This type of error usually indicates that ansible is not installed correctly in your python (v)env (module version mismatch, missing deps....). Try to install ansible in a fresh venv to see if it fixes the problem. If you would like to fix your actual (v)env, you can try to force ansible reinstallation and update of all deps like so: `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --upgrade-strategy eager ansible`

Comment: @JR. Any playbook I run shows the same error output, but the playbook runs fine. so `ansible-playbook any_playbook_here.yml` basically

And my $PATH is: `/home/my_username/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: @Zeitounator I installed ansible with apt.

Comment: my $0.02: `apt remove ansible && pip install ansible`

Comment: @Zeitounator Running ansible after installing with pip gives me the exact same output. I also got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at the end of the pip install.

I've had ansible for quite a while. This problem is recent. I'm about ready to just make backups of my home folder and reinstall my OS. I was also greeted with an initramfs prompt I had to fix this morning, so I have other problems going on.

Comment: Yikes! Hopefully if you need to reinstall this strange issue will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been getting the same sort of error since upgrading to ansible 2.9 and while we don't have every occurrence solved, I can point to some of the sources.

The keyerror is coming from the format being set in ansible itself here - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/a7837edcf26e1e8542109952a9117e145c4cba1d#diff-b433171851ee6e9ab6c4f98f233678b5R65

We have a custom logged so were able to adjust our log messages

```
-self.logger.info(message)
+self.logger.info(message, extra={'user':user})
```

This doesn't solve the KeyError when other applications have their own logger and do log calls. Those still hit the KeyError and fail to log.

Edit: This has been confirmed as a bug and fixed in ansible master - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/65249

Comment: Thanks for the info! I had another problem going on with my machine (it was booting into an initramfs prompt), so I completely reinstalled my OS and ansible. I'm running 2.9.2. All is well now. I'll go ahead an accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after my crash on boot this morning (got an `initramfs` prompt, which led me to run `fsck` while in grub), I decided to just go ahead an reinstall my OS. I reinstalled Ansible using apt, ran the playbook with `ansible-playbook <my_playbook>.yml` and it completed without the errors. This is not a solution, per se, since I obviously had other problems going on, but the python error is gone.